# SVN hosted on windows to access from linux

Tags: linux

SVN is hosted on a windows machine & i need to access it from a linux shell script. Please can anyone help me on this. any help would be appreciable. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the same way as usually. [Here is a good Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/subversion-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: that shows how to setup the repository on windows. but my question is different. i have a repository on windows & i need to download som files from that repository through linux script to linux system.

Comment: do i need to install any client on my linux system or what are the commands i can use to access the repository on windows.

Comment: @rad: no, that shows how to use SVN on Linux via the command line (which is how you usually do it there). It does not matter what it's hosted on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for an equivalent TurtoiseSVN under windows for Linux (I hope I've understood your question correctly!). If this is the case, have a look at this post:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/tortoise-svn-equivalent-in-linux-645058/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the command `svn help` ? If you get an error message that means svn is not installed on your linux machine.  So you have to install it first. Google *install svn ubuntu* or whatever your linux distribution is.

Then you have to checkout the code from your windows machine. The command is `svn checkout "/path/to/source/code/"`

Then you can use the usual svn commands. The cheat sheet suggested by Sebastian is a good start.